# Fill Textbox text dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I have this Array with the name of each property of a class and value type...

```
public string[,] test = new string[,] 
    { 
        { "s", "ID", "textBox" }, 
        { "s", "Status", "" }, 
        { "s", "User", "" }, 
        { "s", "JobTitle", "textBox" }, 
        { "s", "Number", "textBox" }, 
        { "s", "Club", "" },
```

since every textbox in my form starts with "txt" I can have all the textbox names dynamically..

```
            for (int i = 0; i < (mobile.test.Length / 3); i++)
            {
                if (mobile.test[i, 2] == "textBox")
                {
                    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                    string textBoxName = "txt" + mobile.test[i, 1];
```

And I can have my classe property values through reflection, dynamically, like:

```
                    var type = mobile.GetType();
                    var property = type
                                     .GetProperty(mobile.test[i, 1])
                                     .GetValue(mobile);
```

So my goal is to fill all the textboxes with the class property values, but I cant seem to find how to... I have tried something like this but I can't get the textboxes name to an object

```
                    object obj = tb
                               .GetType()
                               .GetProperty("Name")
                               .SetValue(tb, textBoxName); --> this doens't work

                    obj
                     .GetType()
                     .GetProperty("Text")
                     .SetValue(obj, Convert.ToString(property), null);
```

but this is not working... :(

UPDATE1:

Ok I got it working like this:

```
string textBoxName = "txt" + mobile.test[i, 1];
object[] tb = this.Controls.Find(textBoxName, true);
object obj = tb[0];
Type mobileType = mobile.GetType();
var property = mobileType.GetProperty(mobile.test[i, 1]).GetValue(mobile);

obj.GetType().GetProperty("Text").SetValue(obj, Convert.ToString(property), null);
```

although it works I wonder if it is the best way... ? thank you

Comment: are you using asp.net or winforms or wpf? why don't you store your textboxes in an array?

Comment: @DanielA.White It's Winforms...I'm not shure I understood your question..

Comment: I don't understand why you need reflection. In this case you seem to have everything you need to directly use the objects and properties and then the Texboxs. Could you explain a bit more what is that you want to accomplish?

Comment: I can't get the textboxes in the for Loop to fill them with the Var Property value. I need a object, like the obj I have in the example that is the textbox itself with the text property...

Comment: @Nuno are you doing that on the codebehind of your form? or where are you doing the code? How is that you are reaching your properties?

Comment: For each appropriate row in test you are making a TextBox (tb) without adding it to the forms' controls and without setting its location on the form. Is this what you really want or the textboxes are already on the form and you want to find them?

Comment: @Dzyann yes in the code behind of the form..

Comment: @Alireza Yes the textboxes are already in the form...

Comment: @Nuno So why are you making the (dangling) textboxes? Simply grasp the textboxes on the form and set their appropriate property. May be this is the problem. Isn't it?

Comment: @Nuno when you say it is not working, what is happening? Do you get an exception? Maybe the get of the properties you are trying to access is not accessible? Are you getting an exception? or it simply is not showing any value on the form? Additionally why don't you simple do texbox.Text = instance.Property? What is the compelling need for reflection?

Comment: @Dzyann Because I have 30 textboxes and have a bunch of ohter forms with more textboxes, and this way I can have them fill dynamically without having to enter all textboxes on the code... this is not working because the object OBJ I have created equals a void function.. . so this isn't the right way... I feel I'm very cloose ..:)

Comment: @Nuno But you had to take the job to create the array anyway, so you already typed everything, and reflection has the disadvantage that if you change a property name you will have an issue. What is that object you have created? you should be handling the TextBox Directly.

Comment: @Dzyann I just need to create a object that corresponds to the correct textbox.. for example (object obj = The textbox with the name txtID)

Comment: @Nuno I think I understand now, if you already have the texbox in your form, you don't need to create any texbox or any weird obj, just use the texbox in the Form already. You need to search for them. You can use what jvanrhyn or bland posted as answers.

Comment: @Nuno Using reflection like you are using it, to solve your problem, is actually an overkill. You have to be careful to keep the name of the texbox matching the names of the Properties of the class. You had to anyway write all the names of the properties on the arrays, you created all the TexBox with the matching names. And now if you by chance change the name of one of your properites (you or anyone else matter of fact) you won't have an error at compilation time, you will get one at run time. So you have made your system more vulnerable.

Comment: If you wanted to do something more generic you could have done maybe a list of lambda expressions with the properties you wanted to show and then starting from that lambda expression list you could create the Textboxes on the fly.

Comment: @Dzyann I always name my object the name of the properties they get...   I need to read more about lambda expressions.. :( creating the textboxes on the fly seems to complicated for me... Thank you for your help by the way, most appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

As this is a WinForms application you do have access to the Controls collection of the form. Keeping in line with you code example above you can get the actual TextBox doing something like this.

```
var tb = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(textBoxName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

if (tb != null)
{
    tb.Text = property; 
}
```

In this example property is the value you retrieve here:

```
var type = mobile.GetType();
                    var property = type
                                     .GetProperty(mobile.test[i, 1])
                                     .GetValue(mobile);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're taking Reflection way too far.  If you know where the controls are, use the `Controls` collection on that control and get the textboxes.

```
foreach(var tb in parentControl.Controls.Where(c => c is TextBox))
    tb.Text = propVals[i++];
```

Where `propVals` is the collection of values you are already retrieving.  `i` is an `int` counter to keep enumerate the collection.

Also, I assumed you wanted the text set, since you talk of visually seeing this.  However, your code makes me believe you want to set the textbox Names (which is not visual).  If your code is accurate, then you'd just do `tb.Name = propVals[i++];` instead.

Or if you have multiple textboxes and are in fact going by the name, then do `.Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("txt")`

Lastly, a note about `parentControl.Controls` -- it is not recursive so it will not go down into sub-panels etc.

---

*Edit:*
I might understand this better now, though I apologize if I haven't.

```
Type mobileType = mobile.GetType();
foreach(var tb in parentControl.Controls.Where(c => c is TextBox))
    tb.Text = mobileType.GetProperty(tb.Name).GetValue(mobile).ToString();
```

Comment: the textboxes names have the same name of the classe properties, with a "txt" in the begining. I dont understand how you get the correct property value to the corresponding textbox. It has to be the correct one. My porperty var, in the example, has the value of the i array

Comment: I can't set the foreach inside the FOr Loop.. or all the textboxes will have the same value, the last i loop...

Comment: @Nuno With the last update that bland added you just needed to remove the "txt" from the tb.Name. That way you will get the property and you will be able to set it: var propertyName = tb.Name.Substring(3, tb.Name.Length - 3);